# converting a string to Keys in C#

Tags: c#, key, keystroke, typeconverter

Lets say we store KeyCode value as a string. How do you convert it back to KeyCode?

For example, I've captured a key on keydown event:

```
string modifier = e.Modifiers.ToString(); // Control
string key_string = e.KeyCode.ToString(); // D1
```

How to do the following ?

```
Keys old_key_restored = (Keys)key_string;
```

Code above doesn't work.

EDIT: Daniel is a life savior ;)

```
Keys key_restored = (Keys) Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), key_key);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its just an enum so you can use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx)