# Globalhotkey - Reading the wanted Hotkey from text file

Tags: c#, hotkeys, global-hotkey

So I'm using GlobalHotkeys to register my hotkeys.
but i want instead of just make a key without being able to change it, so it will be possible to change it from a .txt File.
so tried something like that:
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsxFk.png)

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Keys.txt"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                ghk = new Hotkeys.GlobalHotkey(Hotkeys.Constants.NOMOD, Keys.Insert, this); }
```

Now how do i make it read the hotkey that .txt file include ?
Need Instead of "Keys.Insert" to be whatever hotkey that inside the text file
it's always says:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLIg9.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060513/converting-a-string-to-keys-in-c-sharp

Comment: Tried and it says that: https://puu.sh/EUZ5v/58f4468e52.png

Comment: It properly recommend TryParse(), not Parse.  And you're supposed to put "S" in the text file, not "Keys.S".  Do not turn the S key into a hotkey, you break the machine.

Comment: @HansPassant i figured it out by doing this:https://puu.sh/EUZAS/9a96b0129c.png

Comment: But now i got this problem: https://puu.sh/EUZCB/45bc1134f1.png with that the program know what key i actually pressed, and i cant put the "key" there