# KeysConverter ConvertFrom ERROR when upgrade from dotnet 6 to dotnet 7 Preview 6 (Windows Forms)

Tags: winforms, .net-7.0

i have windows forms project with following code:

```
string keysVal = "G"
Keys myKeys;
KeysConverter? keyConvert = new KeysConverter();

myKeys = (Keys)keyConvert.ConvertFrom(keysVal);
```

this code run on dotnet 6, but failed on dotnet 7

error:

```
StackTrace = "   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException[T](T key)\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)\r\n   at System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)\r\n ...


Message = "The given key 'G' was not present in the dictionary."
```

any solutions?

or just bugs from dotnet 7?

Comment: Does this `bool valid = Enum.TryParse<Keys>("g", true, out Keys key);` work?

Comment: Anyway, check the [KeysConverter class initializer](https://source.dot.net/#System.Windows.Forms/System/Windows/Forms/KeysConverter.cs,18)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060513/converting-a-string-to-keys-in-c-sharp for other references, just found it right now, and then read your comment, thanks BTW.

Comment: but, why dotnet 6 Works, and dotnet 7 not working, strange.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060513/converting-a-string-to-keys-in-c-sharp or Jimi answer is okay too. same.

Comment: Have you tried `var key = new KeysConverter().ConvertFromString("G");` or the version where you specify a `CultureInfo` (otherwise it uses CurrentCulture)? -- This converter is meant to handle localization.

Comment: error. still not working with var key = new KeysConverter().ConvertFromString("G");

Comment: The .Net 7 repository shows that the `[Converter].ConvertFrom()` method only considers the Keys that are added to the Dictionary in the TypeConverter initialization proc. Previously, the `Enum.Parse()` method was called if the key was not in the Dictionary.

Comment: oh, thanks Jim for the info, very useful for me.